# Stabilization of embedding?

Tags: reference-request, differential-topology, definition

In D. Freed's [lecture notes](https://www.ma.utexas.edu/users/dafr/M392C-2012/Notes/lecture4.pdf) he mentions "stabilization of embedding" in theorem 4.48.  Does anyone know the definition?  I can't find it online.

Comment: Have you tried to look at the definition of stabilizer of an element of a group and using as group the Group of homeomorphisms? i'm still working on your question

Comment: @AHandsomeAlien: the group of homeomorphisms? But you see that the codomain is "doubled" from $\mathbb{A}^{2n+1}$ to $\mathbb{A}^{2n+1} \times \mathbb{A}^{2n+1}$.

Comment: but and embedding defines a homeomorphism on its image,i might be wrong in such approach tho

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He explicitly says in 4.48(ii) that the stabilization of $f: M \to \Bbb R^k$ is the map $\tilde f: M \to \Bbb R^k \times \Bbb R^k$ given by $\tilde f(x) = (0,f(x))$. That is, you compose with the inclusion $i: \Bbb R^k \to \Bbb R^k \times \Bbb R^k$ given by $i(x) = (0,x)$.

(Normally I would say that composing with the obvious linear embedding $\Bbb R^k \to \Bbb R^{k+1}$ is a stabilization, and would phrase this theorem as "after stabilizing sufficiently many times, every embedding is isotopic"; if $M$ is an $n$-manifold, it suffices to stabilize $n+2$ times by the relative Whitney embedding theorem, as applied to $M \times I$: Every embedding of $M$ into $\Bbb R^{2n+3}$ is isotopic. But Freed prefers to bake in that last statement into the definition of stabilization, so that you only need to stabilize once.)

Comment: Yes Mike, the definition is clear.  But what I don't really understand is why it is called "stabilization".  Does it mean that the set of isotopic classes of embeddings stabilizes after sufficiently many inclusions like $\mathbb{R}^k \hookrightarrow \mathbb{R}^{k+1}$?  And why is $(2n + 1) + (2n + 1)$ sufficient?

Comment: @PhysicsMath But your question was what the definition was :) There is only one isotopy class after enough stabilizations, yes. The point is that with high enough dimension (actually, you only need $k = 2n+3$), the relative Whitney embedding theorem (with respect to the boundary of $M \times I$) as applied to a homotopy between the two embeddings, provides an embedding of $M \times I$ into $\Bbb R^{2k+3}$, hence an isotopy between the two embeddings.

Comment: I see, Mike.  You gave the bound and that makes it clear!  Could you append this to your answer to let people understand the mysterious $\mathbb{R}^{2k+1} \times \mathbb{R}^{2k+1}$?